# eslint returns Import in body of module; reorder to top even after rules set (npm project inside npm project)

Tags: reactjs, npm, eslint

So I have an npm project created with CRA inside an npm project (linked with npm link)

```
.
└── thavasantonio/
    ├── node_modules/
    ├── src/
    │   └── projects/
    │       └── quick-type/
    │           ├── node_modules/
    │           ├── src/
    │           ├── package.json
    │           ├── eslintrc.json
    │           └── .eslintignore
    ├── package.json
    ├── eslintrc.json
    └── eslintignore
```

**thavasantonio .eslintrc** i have specified

```
"rules": {
    "import/first": "off",
    "import/order": "off",
}
```

and the **thavasantonio .eslintignore**

```
node_modules/
dist/
/src/projects/quick-type/node_modules/
```

i did the same thing for the quicktype eslint configs
except **.eslintignore**

```
node_modules/
dist/
```

Im using `eslint ^5.12.0` `npm 7.3.0` `node v18.16.1`

When I run `npm start` in thavasantonio I get

```
./src/projects/quick-type/node_modules/@mui/material/LinearProgress/LinearProgress.js
  Line 11:  Import in body of module; reorder to top  import/first
```

but when i do `npx eslint .`  that error doesnt come up.

What am I doing wrong?